# How to find a End Portal on XBOX 360

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I am currently helping someone find their End Portal on their world with the latest updates on the 360 console. We used the Eye of Ender and it did lead us to a big stronghold with a big library, some stairways, silverfish blocks and a bunch of hallways. We consulted YouTube and the videos we watched confirmed what we should be looking for but we still haven't found the portal. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just keep looking around, it certainly sounds like you're in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use more Eyes of Ender from within the fortress to pinpoint the spot where the Ender Portal is.  When it floats in place when you throw it, dig up and down from where it hovers and you should find the portal.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is go above ground, and then get a little height (climb a tree or nerd-pole up a bit), then throw a few Eyes of ender. The point where it touches the ground should be *directly above the portal room*.

However, if you are still in the fortress, it is best to stay on one level (as best you can) while following the Eyes. When they float down tho the floor, the portal is beneath you. It will be hard to determine if the portal is above you because a) I believe that the portal spawns on the lower levels of the dungeon anyway, and b) there is a low ceiling, so the Eyes will always be hitting the ceiling.

However, if the eyes gravitate to the same spot, it (should) be above you.

You could also try the "[X-ray vision glitch](http://youtu.be/UwJS_Ownu4w)" to attempt to see the portal: Set up a redstone circuit that will use a piston to push a block of tnt onto your head. If done right, you shouldn't get any suffocation damage.

[image]

Make sure the redstone doesn't connect to the TNT!

Alternatively, depending on when the world was made (specifically if it was made prior to 'The End' update), it is possible the portal has never even spawned, and the Eyes are only showing where it *should* be, even though it's not. If that is the case, create a new world with the same seed. The portal will spawn in that world. **NOTE: this is only possible if you know the original seed.**

Comment: Nice answer!  But can you even do seeding in the console version?

Comment: I think so... not sure. Asked this question to make sure: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/182485/can-you-get-the-minecraft-seed-on-xbox

Comment: As it turns out, you can't retrieve a seed from a world without knowing it to begin with (i.e. entering it manually during world creation).

Comment: TNT's too dangerous. Best with glowstone.