# Can you get the Minecraft seed on xbox?

Tags: xbox-360, minecraft-legacy-console

I was wondering if/how to get the world seed to create a parallel-world for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get a seed unless you manually enter it.

It is, by default, not an observable aspect of the world generation.  The seed that is generated by the game is hidden, whether on purpose or not is unclear.

Comment: I know you could get it on pc in earlier versions by looking in the "F3" options, there's no variant of this on console?

Comment: As far as I know you can't access the console on any Xbox game without modification.

Comment: You cannot do this on either console version. I'm fairly certain there are working converters though, to be able to use your Xbox version save on PC. If you were to do that, you could presumably see a seed. Then seed would probably not generate the same map on consoles again though, as the versions are coded quite differently. The legality of such converters is also very questionable.

Comment: I don't think legality would be an issue at all.  Mojang has a track record of being okay with a huge variety of modding, and I think that something that would not be harmful in any way would be no problem.

Comment: It's more likely about breaking Microsoft's policies than Minecraft's, as consoles are really tight on what's allowed. I haven't really looked into it, just know from friends it exists.